# Why current ViewController is changed when navigating to another ViewController in iOS with swift

Tags: ios, swift

I am trying to navigate from one screen to another and want to show current screen in the background by setting Alpha value of the target screen, but when I am landing to the target screen background ViewController is not the same from where I landed. I am using below code to navigate

```
let visitorModalVc = UIStoryboard(name: "VisitorInfo", bundle: nil).instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "visitor_modal_vc") as! VisitorInfoModalViewController
visitorModalVc.modalPresentationStyle = .fullScreen


self.present(visitorModalVc, animated: false, completion: nil)
```

It is working fine when I am using visitorModalVc.modalPresentationStyle = .popover but .popover is crashing in tab

Comment: Use `.overFullScreen` instead.

Comment: i am wondering what value you set to the alpha of the target screen. isn't it 0? do you want to use the presenting vc as a background of the presented vc and set the alpha value to a view of the presented vc in order to make the background be seen through? // UPDATE: i found your comment updated right after leaving this comment :-)

Comment: no value of alpha is 1 not touching that

Comment: use modalPresentationStyle = .overCurrentContext.
and make your second view controller clear color